# Stringbuilder problem creating dynamic links

Tags: asp.net, stringbuilder

I'm having an issue creating a link like `"<a href="javascript:window.open('www.microsoft.com');">Visit Microsoft</a>` using stringbuilder. I am adding html to a panel dynamically and I am trying to create a popup link.

The problem is that for some reason the link gets "mixed up". For example:

```
Dim s As String
sb.Append("<A HREF='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open(")
sb.Append("'")
sb.Append("Match.aspx?MatchID=")
sb.Append(mt.MatchID)
sb.Append("&batchid=")
sb.Append(mb.batchID)
sb.Append("')>")
sb.Append("Match</A>")
```

gives an output of :

```
<a match.aspx?matchid="28840&amp;batchid=26596')" onclick="window.open(" href="javascript:void(0)">Match</a>
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, it even does this kind of crap for a regular string!

Please help!

Comment: Does the app behave the same way on any other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, plus a declaration of a Stringbuilder, that I pasted into [**LINQPad**](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
Sub Main
Dim sb As New Stringbuilder
Dim s As String
sb.Append("<A HREF=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""window.open(")
sb.Append("'")
sb.Append("Match.aspx?MatchID=")
sb.Append("45") 'Used random numbers for MatchID
sb.Append("&batchid=")
sb.Append("45") 'Used random numbers for batchid
sb.Append("')")
sb.Append(""">")
sb.Append("Match</A>")
Console.WriteLine(sb)
End Sub
```

And here is what I got

[image: Here is what I got.]
<sub>(source: [angelfire.com](http://www.angelfire.com/ri2/DMX/stringbuilder.jpg))</sub>

Besides the output not being HTML format, I cannot see how we get different results.

#### EDIT:

I have changed the code around to produce HTML format along with an updated photo.

Comment: Thank You!Thank You!Thank You!Thank You!Thank You!Thank You!Thank You!Thank You! a hundred times more!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your output isn't a valid HTML:

```
<A HREF='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open('Match.aspx?MatchID=10&batchid=10')>Match</A>
```

You need to output this HTML:

```
<A HREF="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('Match.aspx?MatchID=10&batchid=10')">Match</A>
```

How about:

```
Dim s As String
sb.Append("<A HREF=""javascript:void(0)"" onclick=""window.open(")
sb.Append("'")
sb.Append("Match.aspx?MatchID=")
sb.Append(mt.MatchID)
sb.Append("&batchid=")
sb.Append(mb.batchID)
sb.Append("')>""")
sb.Append("Match</A>")
```

What you need to do is to make sure that the output is a valid HTML, and you don't mix the attributes quotes with the JavaScript string quotes.

**Edit:** Just noticed that this is VB, so the escaped character need to be "".

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using this.

```
Dim s as string
s = "<A HREF='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open('Match.aspx?MatchID=" _
    & mt.MatchID & "&batchid=" & mb.batchID & "')Match</A>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using string.Format?

```
stringToFormat.Format("<A HREF="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('Match.aspx?MatchID={0}&batchid={1}')">Match</A>", mt.MatchID, mb.batchID);
```

Also helps you see the string clearly in examples like this and the mistakes in the HTML pop out at you. Fixed some quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using sb.Append like that is a bit long winded - an alternative is:

```
string myHTML = string.Format("<A HREF='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open(\"Match.aspx?MatchID={0}&batchid={1}\")'>Match</A>"
              ,mt.MatchID
              ,mb.batchID
             );
```

note the mixed use of single and double quotes in the onclick() function.

Of course maybe an even better way is to declare a new HTML element like this:

```
HtmlLiteral myAnchor = new HtmlLiteral("A");
myAnchor.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:void(0);");
myAnchor.Attributes.Add("onclick", "my javascript");
...etc...
myPanel.Controls.Add(myAnchor);
```